# Installed SQL Express on IaaS VM in Azure, SQL Virtual Machine resource appeared in resource group?

Tags: virtual-machine, sql-server, azure, sql, microsoft

I installed SQL Express on a Windows Server VM in Azure, a few days later a new resource appeared in the RG with the same resource name of the VM but as a SQL Virtual Machine.

I take it this won't incur any additional charges? also kind of interesting as I couldn't find any documentation about this but maybe I didn't look hard enough.

Answer (score 0):

The SQL Virtual Machine resource was created when you installed SQL Express on your Windows Server VM in Azure. This resource is used to manage SQL Server instances running on Azure Virtual Machines.

You are not supposed to get charged by a SQL Server Express Edition instance, but my suggestion is to examine the Azure Billing Page [here](https://portal.azure.com/#view/Microsoft_Azure_CostManagement/Menu/%7E/costanalysisv3) and make sure there are no additional charges.